# Using S3Tools Client Side Encryption and Copy from S3 to Redshift

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, gnupg, s3cmd

I am using the S3cmd put with an -e flag to encrypt a file.

When I try to copy the file to Redshift (from S3) I get an error. I am using my passphrase converted to AES256 as my master key.

```
copy xxx 
from 'xxx' 
access_key_id 'xxx'
secret_access_key 'xxx'
master_symmetric_key 'xxx' 
IGNOREHEADER 8
encrypted
delimiter ',';
```

I receive an error that looks like this:

```
ERROR: XX000: Failed writing body (0 != ) Cause: S3 object 'xxx' does not have 'x-amz-meta-x-amz-key' metadata
```

Comment: Please elaborate by giving a more detailed example and describe exactly what steps you took and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: Encryption seems to have gone well. I can decrypt the file in command line using GPG but the passphrase gives me trouble when copying from S3 to Redshift. I don't know where there was an issue in the process.

Comment: Looks like I am having same issue. Did you found a solution?